# Trouble with an R function for making a ggplot2 graph and optionally facetting with user-specified columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, non-standard-evaluation

I'd like to write a function in R for making some graphs and, optionally, facetting those graphs by whatever column the user inputs. I'd prefer to do this using nonstandard evaluation since I don't know what columns the user will have in the data.frame that they input. The code below works, and the user can specify what column they want to color points by:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(rlang)
 data("diamonds")
 
 myplot <- function(DF, colorBy){      
  colorBy <- rlang::enquo(colorBy)      
  ggplot(DF, aes(x = price, y = carat, color = !!colorBy)) +
        geom_point()      
  }
  
  myplot(diamonds, colorBy = cut)
```

[image: diamonds graph]

but this code, where I was trying to allow the user to specify a column to facet by, fails:

```
myplot_facet <- function(DF, colorBy, facetBy){
  
  colorBy <- rlang::enquo(colorBy)
  facetBy <- rlang::enquo(facetBy)
  ggplot(DF, aes(x = price, y = carat, color = !!colorBy)) +
        geom_point() +
        facet_wrap(. ~ !!facetBy)
 }
 
 myplot_facet(diamonds, colorBy = cut, facetBy = color)
```

The error I get is

> Error: Quosures can only be unquoted within a quasiquotation context.
>
> # Bad:   list(!!myquosure)
>
> # Good:   dplyr::mutate(data, !!myquosure)

I'm not sure how to use that error message to solve my issue. Does `facet_wrap` have different input requirements from `aes`? I thought they were both calling on columns in a data.frame using tidy syntax, so I thought they would work similarly.

As a further complication, I'd like it if the user could set `facetBy` to NA if they don't want facets.

I've been trying to read up on similar problems ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034811/ggplot2-not-recognizing-a-column-in-a-function-call), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36683174/lazy-evaluation-for-ggplot2-inside-a-function), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45439813/pass-function-arguments-to-both-dplyr-and-ggplot)) and I'm trying to decipher the [NSE chapter from "Advanced R"](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html), but I am struggling. None of the other questions are *quite* what I'm asking, and the NSE chapter from "Advanced R" is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
myplot_facet <- function(DF, colorBy, facetBy){
  
  facetBy <- enquo(facetBy)
  
  ggplot(DF, aes(x = price, y = carat, color = {{colorBy}} )) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(vars(!!facetBy))
}

myplot_facet(diamonds, colorBy = cut, facetBy = color)
```